# Hide admin email address in user's from field (Webform)

Tags: 7, forms, webforms, emails

I am using the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform)  module. 
So far the user can send an email via a form to my admin email.

However when I reply to the user my admin email address shows in their 'from' field! - How do I hide that to the site's name (but still pointing to my admin email address)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After saving the new component, visit the emails tab. Select the newly created component from the "Component value" select list and select add. The final results will look similar to this.

[image]